# WPF Forbid System.Windows.Shapes.Path clicktrough?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom control I made, that contains few `System.Windows.Shapes.Path` s and a `Textblock` in a `Canvas` container. When I use this control, whenever I click it, it's parent (which also happends to be `Canvas`) control's click event fires aswell.
How to eliminate this unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Click event method for the child control will look something like:

```
private void CustomControl_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
// code
}
```

All you need to do is set `e.Handled = true;` somewhere in this method to prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent control.

Comment: Yes, that was an easy one :)